# Use "nohup" to run "top" command in background

Tags: bash, signals, nohup

I have problems in using nohup to run top command in the background. First, I run it locally, as

```
nohup top &
```

it complains in `nohup.out` with text `top: failed to get tty`. My ultimate goal is to run top on remote machine, like

```
nohup ssh -t user@hostname top &
```

currently, the above command also fails with

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.^M 
TERM environment variable not set
```

Any ideas?

PS: I run this command to ping `machineB` from `machineA`. `machineA` is always alive, but not not always logged in.

Comment: You could use screen. It will open a terminal, you then run top, and you can detach (Ctrl+a then d) to quit but leave screen running in the backgroung. If you don't mind me asking, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am confused by _why_ you want to do this.

Comment: @JanitoVaqueiroFerreiraFilho I have to use nohup which is builtin in my linux distribution, and I dont have root access to install ``screen``

Comment: Echoing @tcaswell - why would you want to do this? The purpose of `nohup` is to keep something running if the tty it's attached to goes away for some reason. If `top` doesn't have a tty, though, there is no way to examine it's output, or to provide input to `top`, and so keeping it running is pretty meaningless. And, short of using `screen` or `dtach` or something, there's no way to re-attach it to a tty to make it useful again...

Comment: I think you want to look in to cron jobs http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/ which will run a command at specified time interval.  Can you elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to do?

Comment: @tcaswell I am trying to ping certain remote machine, to keep it live. I updated the OP.

Comment: How much do you need to do to machineB to keep it alive and how often do you have to do it?

Answer (score 15):

Have you tried the -b (batch mode) switch of the top command?

Comment: I would suggest adding "of the top command", just for a little more clarity. +1 for the answer though =)